# Visual Basic - Automation Loop

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, loops

Im developing a bot to help me upload certain things to my website so this is the code for automation

how can i loop this and make it each time read same text box but different line 
For example im having 2 textbox which it does upload

first textbox : (number)

second textbox: (url)

so what im gonna need is to write like 10 codes and 10 urls and when i press the button i want it to loop on these functions but each time it does take the other line in the same textbox

for example: 1st textbox contain 4 different lines

2nd textbox contain 4 different lines

so each time it does load the 1 line from 1st textbox and 1 line from 2nd textbox and after finishing it does stop

any helpers ?

```
`    Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click

    objIE.Document.GetElementById("imdb_id").Focus()
    objIE.Document.GetElementById("imdb_id").InnerText = imdb.Text$
    objIE.Document.GetElementById("import_btn").InvokeMember("Click")
    Delay(5)
    objIE.Document.Forms(0).InvokeMember("submit")
    Delay(5)
    objIE.Document.GetElementById("link-active").InvokeMember("Click")
    objIE.Document.GetElementById("selected-source").SetAttribute("value", "embed")
    objIE.Document.GetElementById("video_url").Focus()
    objIE.Document.GetElementById("video_url").InnerText = TextBox2.Text$
    objIE.Document.GetElementById("add-link").InvokeMember("Click")
    Delay(2)


End Sub`
```

Comment: You should use a DataGridView with two columns...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rough draft...add a DataGridView and set it up with two columns:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Entries As New List(Of Tuple(Of String, String))
    Private EntriesEnum As IEnumerator(Of Tuple(Of String, String))

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If IsNothing(EntriesEnum) Then
            Entries.Clear()
            For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2 ' ignore last row (for adding new rows)
                Entries.Add(New Tuple(Of String, String)(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value, DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value))
            Next
            If Entries.Count > 0 Then
                EntriesEnum = Entries.GetEnumerator
                DataGridView1.Enabled = False
                Button1.PerformClick()
            End If
        ElseIf EntriesEnum.MoveNext Then
            Dim current As Tuple(Of String, String) = EntriesEnum.Current
            Debug.Print(current.Item1 & ", " & current.Item2)
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Done!")
            EntriesEnum = Nothing
            DataGridView1.Enabled = True
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: i still dont get it how im supposed to link this with the 

    objIE.Document.GetElementById("imdb_id").InnerText = imdb.Text$

and make it also loop

Comment: I don't know either.  You'd need to update your question and **show an example** of what's in both of the TextBoxes, along with how those TextBoxes relate to the piece of code you already posted.  It's not clear to me where those values are coming from...